# Servlet mapping is not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I have created a simple program by using JSP and Servlets. After all, i have set and mapped my servlet in web.xml like below. But i am getting blank page always.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>exampleServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/exampleServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My JSP file looks like this.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form action ="exampleServlet" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table width="500" style="margin-top:100px;">
            <tr>
                <td>Subject</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="subj" id="subj"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Upload File</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="upload_file" id="upload_file"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any exampleServlet is,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.servlet.ServletException; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class exampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void init() {

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String sub = request.getParameter("subj");
        System.out.println(sub);
    }
}
```

My file Structure is,

```
JSP file  --> tomcat/webapps/application/index.jsp

Servlet   --> tomcat/webapps/application/WEB-INF/classes/exampleServlet.class
```

Where i went wrong? What is the mistake i have made? Can you please suggest me?

**EDIT :** I am posting my form elements to that servlet. By that time it passes the URL like this `http://localhost:8080/application/exampleServlet`

Comment: How are you trying to access it, and when is it giving the blank page?

Comment: What else do you expect to get if your doPost method doesn't do anything except prints?

Comment: @NilsH I have edited my post with the required details. Please see that

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis I want to get the filepath of the selected file to upload. But initially i want to test whether the flow goes well. Thats why i am printing the value. But it is not coming inside the function.

Comment: which tomcat container, you are using ?

Comment: You are not printing anything to the response...Did you check your console output since you are printing to `System.out`?

Comment: @ajduke tomcat - 7.0.39

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything is fine in your application. You are getting blank page because your `doPost` method doesn't do anything. It prints the value only to the console output.

Change it to for e.g.:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.print("something");
}
```

And then take a look if `something` appears in the browser.

Comment: I changed like this. But it is not working. Again it shows blank page

Comment: Have you restarted Tomcat after you've made the changes?

Comment: OMG. I went mad. I was keep on trying without restarting Tomcat. Now it is working. Thanks man.

Comment: No problem. Remember after you've made any changes you have to restart servlet container. If you just keep on redeploying your application it will eventually run out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

If the "error" happens when you submit the form, it's because your servlet doesn't render any output, nor return any respons at all. In your `doPost` you're supposed to write a response back to the browser, or hand over the request to something that does.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body>Hello world</body></html>");
}
```

would at least print something, though nothing very useful.

The "proper" thing to do would be to redirect or include a view that does the rendering.

Comment: Set a breakpoint or write something to the console and see if your servlet is at all invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the different `servlet-clas` name than `url-pattern.`

something like following  or vice-versa

```
  <servlet>
            <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>exampleServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/egServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

after the change restart the server

Answer (score -2):

Probably your request doesnt matches the URL pattern. Try like this :

```
<url-pattern>/exampleServlet/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Edited.. This one should go.. /application/ should be in the webcontext path.